# Is it possbie to make an if condition based on Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I need to make some if statements for advanced filter search and also some if conditions to make a table filterable. Is there any way to make if statements based on Firebase. I need to make the output from Firebase true and false to replace with archived and display it in a dynamic table.

Thank you in advance.

e.g.

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");   
var query = usersRef.orderByChild("disabled").equalTo(true);
query.on("value", function(snapshot) { 
snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
  if (user.disabled != true) {     
  $('#ArchiveLabel').text("Archived");
  } else {
    $('#ArchiveLabel').text("");
    }
}); });
```

Comment: Short answer: yes.Long answer: post your code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something along these lines:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
var query = usersRef.orderByChild("something").equalTo(true);
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
    console.log(user.key, user.val());
  });
});
```

I highly recommend that you spend some time in the Firebase documentation, for example its [section on ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). You also might benefit from taking the [Firebase codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you read the question again? I forgot to add some text. Thank you.

Comment: `  if (true) {` will always be true.